# Javascript to Python Text Encoding Error

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, encoding

I have a Google App Engine web app where users can upload some text. In the dev environment everything works fine, however, when switching to production, I have encountered some issues. First, the Python backend couldn't properly handle accented characters (à, è, ...). I then found a solution which correctly reads accented characters but unfortunately fails with the Lorem Ipsum (in prod environment).

Here's what I'm doing now:

Javascript

```
formData.append("text", encodeURI(document.getElementById("question").value));
```

Python

```
text_to_save = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('text').encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
```

I then proceed to save the text in the Datastore.

But with this string:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

I find this in the Datastore:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed%= 20eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliqua.= Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ull= am corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea co= mmodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate%= 20velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `self.request.get('text')` before encoding / decoding / unquoting? And is it the same as the result of `encodeURI(document.getElementById("question").value)` in JavaScript?

Comment: @zvone They differ: the js console outputs the encoded string with %20 replacing the spaces, but in App Engine the same string is read as follows:

Comment: Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipisci%20elit,%20sed%= 20eiusmod%20tempor%20i
ncidunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.= %20Ut%20enim%20ad%20minim%20veniam,%20quis%20nostrum%20exercitationem%20ull= am%20corporis%20suscipit%20laboriosam,%20nisi%20ut%20aliquid%20ex%20ea%20co= mmodi%20consequatur.%20Quis%20aute%20iure%20reprehenderit%20in%20voluptate%= 20velit%20esse%20cillum%20dolore%20eu%20fugiat%20nulla%20pariatur.

Comment: sometimes a '%= ' is used

Comment: I think you use a multiline texarea or inline editor with a line size of 60 chars. The strange chars you see mark the end of a line. Try to delete these eol markers before sending the text.

Comment: Or maybe you can change the wrap attribute of the text area.